# Is there a way to change schema with AWS Amplify?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I have an existing AWS Amplify schema with data deployed to DynamoDB tables.

I want to change the AWS Amplify schema.

When I change the schema, how do I include the data in my old tables and migrate them to the new tables created by AWS Amplify?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this depends on how much you are changing your schema. If you are just adding new attributes to your models or taking away attributes then you won't need to do anything. If you are renaming or creating new models this will get trickier. My advice would be to add all new schema models you want without removing the old ones. Then write a few migration scripts using the dynamodb directly to migrate your data. and then once all of the old data is migrated you can delete your old models.